# Validate the regex result

Tags: php, regex

I have follwing regex to validate get the image from page:

```
preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches);
```

I want to put some condition if matches/not matches. How can I do?

Right now I get the result using:

```
echo $matches[0][0];
```

But if does not match means no image on the page :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

I dont know how to validate the result of preg_match_all

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($matches)` so you can see exactly what the array looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Just check the return value of `preg_match_all` function.

```
$ret = preg_match_all('~\bhttps?://\S+(?:png|jpg)\b~i', $html, $matches);

if ($ret) {
   // matched
   // use $matches array for the result
}
else {
   // didn't match
}
```